# Taking input from a user and using that in webview

Tags: android, webview

i am new to android. I was trying to get input from the user, the input being a url of a site and then opening that in webview. But i cant find anymethod to do that. As soon as i insert anything related to user input in a webviewactivity, the app stops.
Plz tell me how to use user input for webview. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use EditText View , and fetch its data , and assign it into some string

```
String url = edtTextview.getText().toString()
```

and Open that url with some WebView with `loadUrl()` method .

```
try 
{
    URL actualUrl = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection cn = (HttpURLConnection)      
    actualUrl.openConnection(); 
    methodName = cn.getRequestMethod();
    view.loadUrl(url);
}
catch ( Exception err )
{
}
```

Edited Section :

```
    String[] items={"Android","Bluetooth","Chrome"};
    ArrayAdapter aa=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
    final Spinner spin = ( Spinner ) findViewById(R.id.spinner1) ;
    spin.setAdapter(aa);

    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
            Log.i(spin.getSelectedItem().toString(),"tag");

            if ( spin.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Bluetooth"))
            {
                try 
                {
                    URL actualUrl = new URL(url);
                    HttpURLConnection cn = (HttpURLConnection)      
                    actualUrl.openConnection(); 
                    methodName = cn.getRequestMethod();
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                }
                catch ( Exception err )
                {
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
        {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Well its exactly a spinner that i am using. And based upon the item selected in the spinner, i want to go to different sites in the webview. Can you please tell me how to do that. I am fairly new to android so please bear with me. Thanks in advance